# How to Extract JSON Array from MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I am planning to insert a JSON Array into my Database Table for dynamic purposes. I do not have any problem in extracting JSON Objects with Key/Value Pairs, however the opposite it is for JSON Arrays. See below example:

```
[{"LCM": {"id": 333, "barcode": "ABC"}, "DCover": {"id": 444, "barcode": "CDE"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}, {"LCM": {"id": 555, "barcode": "EFG"}, "DCover": {"id": 666, "barcode": "GHI"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}, {"LCM": {"id": 777, "barcode": "IJK"}, "DCover": {"id": 888, "barcode": "KLM"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}]
```

ideally, per each of them above, if extracted - it would look something like this:

```
{"LCM": {"id": 777, "barcode": "IJK"}, "DCover": {"id": 888, "barcode": "KLM"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}
```

now the question is, how can i extract them as so:

```
1. {"LCM": {"id": 333, "barcode": "ABC"}, "DCover": {"id": 444, "barcode": "CDE"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}
2. {"LCM": {"id": 555, "barcode": "EFG"}, "DCover": {"id": 666, "barcode": "GHI"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}
3. {"LCM": {"id": 777, "barcode": "IJK"}, "DCover": {"id": 888, "barcode": "KLM"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}
```

by which of them, will i be then able to parse per needed, i.e.: "$.LCM" or "$.DCover.barcode"

JSON_EXTRACT(`...`) seems to only be available by defining a key to specific JSON Object. But this doesn't work for Value-only JSON Array (as far as i know)

hopefully, i can get a tip here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL >= 8.0.4, you can use `JSON_TABLE`.

#### Example query

```
with tbl(val) as (
  select CAST('[{"LCM": {"id": 333, "barcode": "ABC"}, "DCover": {"id": 444, "barcode": "CDE"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}, {"LCM": {"id": 555, "barcode": "EFG"}, "DCover": {"id": 666, "barcode": "GHI"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}, {"LCM": {"id": 777, "barcode": "IJK"}, "DCover": {"id": 888, "barcode": "KLM"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}]'
  as json
 )
)
select rowid, content from tbl, JSON_TABLE(val, '$[*]' columns (rowid for ordinality, content json PATH '$')) as jt;
```

#### Result

```
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| rowid | content                                                                                                                   |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1 | {"LCM": {"id": 333, "barcode": "ABC"}, "DCover": {"id": 444, "barcode": "CDE"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"} |
|     2 | {"LCM": {"id": 555, "barcode": "EFG"}, "DCover": {"id": 666, "barcode": "GHI"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"} |
|     3 | {"LCM": {"id": 777, "barcode": "IJK"}, "DCover": {"id": 888, "barcode": "KLM"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"} |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 According to my understand you are using JSON Array, use iteration

 CREATE PROCEDURE `Manipulation_Json_Data`()
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  CONTAINS SQL
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
  COMMENT ''
  BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;

  SET @j = '[{"LCM": {"id": 333, "barcode": "ABC"}, "DCover": {"id": 444, "barcode": "CDE"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}, {"LCM": {"id": 555, "barcode": "EFG"}, "DCover": {"id": 666, "barcode": "GHI"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}, {"LCM": {"id": 777, "barcode": "IJK"}, "DCover": {"id": 888, "barcode": "KLM"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}]';

   WHILE v1 < 4 DO
     SET @data_v = JSON_EXTRACT(@j, concat('$[',v1,']'));
     INSERT INTO database.table_name (`ID`, `Text`) VALUES (NULL, @data_v );
     SET v1 = v1 + 1;
   END WHILE;
  END
```

Comment: is this done purely in MySQL? because the goal is to do it entirely in MySQL (the database server) independently

Comment: updated answer please check it. this will save row like this: 1. {"LCM": {"id": 333, "barcode": "ABC"}, "DCover": {"id": 444, "barcode": "CDE"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}
2. {"LCM": {"id": 555, "barcode": "EFG"}, "DCover": {"id": 666, "barcode": "GHI"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}
3. {"LCM": {"id": 777, "barcode": "IJK"}, "DCover": {"id": 888, "barcode": "KLM"}, "date_associated": "2017-11-27 23:59:59"}

Comment: uhm, i'm looking to a MySQL-Server sided solution. Not on any language specifics.